# Difference between 2 bin folders opencv 3.3.1 winpack

Tags: opencv

What exactly is the difference between the two bin folders in the opencv 3.3.1 winpack?

https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.3.1/opencv-3.3.1-vc14.exe/download

[file structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHY4R.png)